# How to impute a highly sparse binary matrix?

Tags: matrix, data-imputation, sparse

Let's say you begin with a binary matrix (only 0 and 1) and you must impute 60% missing values.

How would you do this? It is possible to use nearest neighbors?

Comment: Could you tell us *why* those values are missing?  What is the mechanism that causes them to be missing?